# Reload markers and list like Foursquare

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I have map similar to foursquare, with sidebar listing places and map showing markers, I return JSON with description and location,on my sidebar list show all markers and not  the markers with showing on map, I want to do like foursquare , when I 'dragend' reload list on sidebar and markers inside bounds of map, how I do that?

Comment: http://foursquare.com/explore

Comment: It's asking for a username/password, which I don't have. You may want to add an image to your question, since it refers to foursquare as the reference implementation and I'm not sure everyone will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Store Locator library](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html).

Disclosure: I wrote it.